# WooCommerce Custom Theme CSS problems with Bootstrap

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I noticed a strange CSS behavior in MyAccount page of WooCommerce.

It happens, when I load bootstrap.min.css in my child-theme. I´m using it for a bootstrap jumbotron element on my custom page.

How can I avoid this? Is bootstrap not compatible?

This is how I load the css file (action wp_enque_scripts)

```
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css', false, NULL, 'all');
```

[image]

```
<div class="u-columns col2-set" id="customer_login">

<div class="u-column1 col-1">
...
</div>

<div class="u-column2 col-2">
...
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: col-2 and col-1 are both css styles in bootstrap css. Sounds like they are conflicting with your grid you have.

Comment: That's right, I tried adding 'if (!is_account_page() )' before loading bootstrap and it worked. But is there another solution to avoid conflicts? I mean, many WooCommerce pages use Bootstrap, I guess

Comment: Remove bootstrap and just copy the style from bootstrap you need for the jumbotron.  Just write some custom css and remove bootstrap.  Custom compile a version of bootstrap without the grid.  There is so many ways to accomplish this.  You even could go into bootstrap.css and comment or remove any styles that are conflicting.  Its really up to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use bootstrap, just override the css rules of my account page by adding a unique class.